# writeBytes(str) vs write(str) in DataOutputStream

Tags: java

What's the difference between `writeBytes(str)` vs `write(str)` in `DataOutputStream`?
And is there any Tips/Tricks to use them?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no `write(String)` method in `DataOutputStream`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DataOutputStream belongs to the OutputStream classes for writing binary data - not Writer for text, It is an old class and `writeBytes(String)` is a weird twitter method as it:

> Each character in the string is written out, in sequence, by
>   discarding its high eight bits. If no exception is thrown, the counter
>   written is incremented by the length of s.

So from every Unicode UTF-16 char (16 bits) the low byte is taken. If the string restricted to 7-bits ASCII, maybe a bit ISO-8859-1, the string is not mangled. But in general information is lost.

There is no counterpart in DataInputStream, no `String readBytes()`.

I would call it a design mishap, as java introduced a separatation from text and binary data (`byte[]`), introducing `byte` and reserving `String`  and 16-bit `char` for Unicode text. The author probably felt a need for a C style `write(char*)`.

*No need to mention writeUTF and DataInputStream.readUTF.*

Answer (score -1):

In `DataOutputStream`, in reference to the *oracle documentation* (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) there isn't any method named `write(String)` but only `write(byte[])`, `write(byte[] b, int off, int len)` and `write(int b)`. So, if you have a `String`, the simplest method you can use is `writeBytes(String)`.

There is no difference between those methods, only use the proper one according to your needs (the type of the object your data are stored in).